# adding UI to current page without using XAML - Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I need to add to the current page some UI but I cannot use XAML.

For instance, I am creating a textBlock this way:

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "text1";
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
myGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);
```

What I need to do in order to display myGrid attached to my current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is building a UI programmatically. Here is a link to an article that explains it

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/programmatically_adding_elements_pg1.htm

Comment: thanks, but I can recognize the LayoutRoot here: this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myGrid); I am running this in such a method Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { ...});

Comment: If you are running this in app.cs then you need to make a RootVisual to be a container and then add your UI controls to that.

Comment: I am not doing it in app.cs but I am creating a phonegap plugin. So I need to do that in a beginInvoke. there I got the current page with var currentPage = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;

Comment: I don't know about Silverlight on windows phone but on the web you just set the RootVisual (in your case RootFrame) to be a new container i.e. a page then add the content to that